# Need Help... So Confused with this QFP32 SA663 Socket

Tags: avr, adapter, pinout, socket, tqfp

I purchased an SA663 clone QFP32 Socket online, but to my extreme dismay, it doesn't work, or at least I haven't been able to get it to. Basically the original SA663 is a 1:1 pinout. But after trying at least a million pinout combos, I can't seem to get this thing to work. From what I can tell it is NOT a 1:1 pinout.

Here is the email I received from the original makers of the SA663. He says they're a 1:1 pinout, but the one I have isn't, and upon inspection of the board, the traces aren't going to the same number pins. It almost looks like DIP1 is going to QFP26+ (I can't tell without separating the two boards, and I don't think I can)

[image: SA663 Original Pinout (Not The Clone Pinout)]

I'm sure one of you mega-geniuses out there has one of these and knows the pinout. I'm about ready to trash this thing. Can't even get the pinout from who I bought it from or anyone who sells them. Major waste.

And in my defense, I had no idea this was a clone. I just thought these were THE programming sockets, not that there was a company being ripped off for designs and such. I feel dumb, but I'm still making some rookie mistakes.

Thanks in advance, friends!

Comment: A bit more detail (pictures, datasheets, anything) on what you *actually have*, rather than what you thought you were getting would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Well if I had any of that, I wouldn't be asking. I'm sure a datasheet would clear things up. And a picture isn't going to do much either because the Xeltek and clone looks identical to the last detail.

This should be the listing here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/261576182550?_trksid=p2060778.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: If that's all you've got then you'll probably have to make friends with your multimeter and 'beep' each pin out to see where it goes ... good luck ...

Comment: Beep each pin out? I'm unfamiliar with this term. I'm also surprised nobody else here has one of these to be honest

Comment: The continuity check function on many multimeters makes a beep when the probes are connected together. So - put probe 1 on pin 1, successively test pins with probe 2 until you get a beep. move probe 1 to pin 2. rinse & repeat.

Comment: Oh gosh, duh. I should've known that . Thanks. That helps more than you know

Answer (score 1):

It seems that DIP1 is connected to QFN29, and then they continue on from there.

Here is the pinout for the Chinese SA663 clone

- QFN29   :   DIP1
- QFN30   :   DIP2
- QFN31   :   DIP3
- QFN32   :   DIP4
- QFN1    :   DIP5
- QFN2    :   DIP6
- QFN3    :   DIP7
- QFN4    :   DIP8
- QFN5    :   DIP9
- QFN6    :   DIP10
- QFN7    :   DIP11
- QFN8    :   DIP12
- QFN9    :   DIP13
- QFN10   :   DIP14
- QFN11   :   DIP15
- QFN12   :   DIP16
- QFN13   :   DIP17
- QFN14   :   DIP18
- QFN15   :   DIP19
- QFN16   :   DIP20
- QFN17   :   DIP21
- QFN18   :   DIP22
- QFN19   :   DIP23
- QFN20   :   DIP24
- QFN21   :   DIP25
- QFN22   :   DIP26
- QFN23   :   DIP27
- QFN24   :   DIP28
- QFN25   :   DIP29
- QFN26   :   DIP30
- QFN27   :   DIP31
- QFN28   :   DIP32